# How to retain selected choices in a javascript quiz?

Tags: javascript, html, web, radio-button

My javascript quiz has 5 questions. 
It has two buttons - next and prev.

How do I make this happen -- When 'prev' button is pressed, the selected choice of previous question must be highlighted.

Here is a function I've used :

```
function createChoices() {
 for(var i=0;i<4;i++)
  {
   if(allQuestions[index].checked == "checked")
    {
     allQuestions[index].choices[userAnswer].checked = "true"
    }
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, the next button which is working in web browser isn't working in JSFiddle.

Comment: I copied it correctly. In the HTML section, the next button's onClick attribute calls updateNext() function , which is defined in my Javascript code.

Comment: yes i am going through the code..indentations are correct.

Comment: when previous clicked { for each checkBox which has been ticked before { thischeckBox.value = "checked" }} does not work ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed a couple of errors in your code/jsfiddle settings:

- changed javascript setting `onLoad` to `No wrap - in <head>`
- combined functions `createQuestion()` and `createChoices()` into 1 `onload` event
- moved `collectUserAnswer()` above `index--` otherwise the checked box will already be replaced

[working DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9nLxas6m/13/)

Comment: Thanks Mr.White, it's working!! I now understood my mistake with collectUserAnswer().. But I didn't find any change in code with NoWrap - in <head> which u stated you've made.

Comment: Having an onload event within the onload event is useless, since the event has already been triggered. That's why I moved it to just wrap in the head. If I change it back to onload, it fails to load the question: http://jsfiddle.net/9nLxas6m/15/

Comment: Okay , now I got it!! But can u please tell me how the next button worked? :) I'm clear with every thing.

Comment: The NEXT button will call `collectUserAnswer()` to update the `userAnswer` property of that question in the JSON object. Then it will increment the `index` and call `createQuestion()` and `createChoices()` using that new `index` value.